# How to convert object to int? (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a task to convert "Egységár" and "Érték" to integer. When I try this code I get this error message.

**Database**:

```
Dátum      :      object
Kategórianév  :   object
Terméknév    :    object
Egységár     :    object
Mennyiség    :   float64
Érték        :    object
Vevőnév       :   object
Vevő megye     :  object
Vevő város     :  object
Bolt megye    :   object
Bolt város   :    object
Boltnév     :     object
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df2=df
pd.to_numeric(df2['Egységár']).astype(int)
```

**Error message:**

ValueError: Unable to parse string "400,00 Ft" at position 0[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLDmr.png)

Comment: is the comma a decimal separator? i.e. 400 feets or 40000 feets?

Comment: It's 400 forint (hungarian money).

Answer (score 0):

Try removing commas and NaN values in the column first:

```py
import pandas as pd
df2=df.copy()
df2['Egységár'] = df2['Egységár'].replace(",", "", regex=True).replace("(\s+)Ft", "", regex=True)
pd.to_numeric(df2[df2['Egységár'].isna()]["Egységár"]).astype(int)
```

If the comma doesn't indicate the seperator between zeros and is the decimal point, try changing the replace from `.replace(",", "", regex=True)` to `.replace(",\d+", "", regex=True)`

Comment: ValueError: Unable to parse string "40000 Ft" at position 0




I typed and got this message.

Comment: @OlíviaSzűcs I have edited the answer, as per your comment

Comment: IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: @OlíviaSzűcs Please provide a shareable part of your dataframe in your question in order for us to have a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Dátum Kategórianév Terméknév Egységár Mennyiség Érték Vevőnév Vevő megye Vevő város Bolt megye Bolt város Boltnév
01/02/2015 Iroda Tol 400,00 Ft 8 3 200 Ft Kovács Bt Pest Gödöllő Heves Eger 2. ABC
01/13/2015 Játék Labda 500,00 Ft 6 3 000 Ft Kovács Bt Pest Gödöllő Heves Gyöngyös 1. ABC
01/23/2015 Játék Labda 500,00 Ft 3 1 500 Ft Nagy Kft Heves Gyöngyös Heves Gyöngyös 1. ABC
01/24/2015 Kert Gereblye 700,00 Ft -4 -2 800 Ft Nagy Kft Heves Gyöngyös Pest Gödöllő 2. ABC

Comment: @OlíviaSzűcs Thanks for coming back to this, Olivia. Please avoid adding the dataframe in the comments. You need to add this dataframe to your own question in a readable and understandable format. Thanks.

Comment: I have added the dataframe to my question as an image.

Comment: @OlíviaSzűcs Take a look at my answer now, check whether or not it is ok. If there's any problem, do not hesitate to comment. Thanks

Comment: ----> 4 pd.to_numeric(df2[df2['Egységár'].isna()]["Egységár"]).astype(int)            

IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Answer (score 0):

If the comma is not a decimal separator:

```
pd.to_numeric(df2['Egységár'].str.replace(r'\D', '', regex=True), errors='coerce')
```

If this is a decimal separator:

```
(pd.to_numeric(df2['Egységár']
   .str.replace(',', '.', regex=False)
   .str.replace(r'[^\d\.]', '', regex=True), errors='coerce')
)
```